# How can I handle Connection timed out error in ruby Net/HTTP?

Tags: ruby, connection

I try this code, but when the proxy is too slow I get connection timed out error. How can I solve this? I tried Exception handling but doesn't work. Can anybody help?

```
 Net::HTTP.new('example.com', nil, '140.113.182.81', '808').start { |http|  

      begin   
        response = http.request  
        p response  
      rescue Timeout::Error  
        p 'timed out'   
      end  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Timeout::Error is raised by the `Net::HTTP.connect` method that is executed by `start`, not by `request`.

It means that in order to rescue the timeout, the whole `Net::HTTP` call should be inside the begin block.

```
  begin   
    Net::HTTP.new('example.com', nil, '140.113.182.81', '808').start do |http|  
      response = http.request  
      p response  
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error  
    p 'timed out'   
  end
```

Comment: This works, but only rescue Exception, with the rescue Timeout::Error not catch the error.

Comment: I didn't understand the comment. Can you clarify it?

Comment: The rescue Timeout::Error didn't catch the error, but the rescue Exception yes.  begin   
    Net::HTTP.new('example.com', nil, '140.113.182.81', '808').start do |http|  
      response = http.request  
      p response  
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error  
    p 'here not'   rescue Exception  p 'here catch the exception'  
  end